# rails select_tag without form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

I have a view displaying buttons to link to reports where I want the user to be able select the sort column for the report.

The select:

```
<%= select_tag 'select_sort_order', "<option>fleet_num</option><option>rego</option>".html_safe %>
```

Then the link:

```
<%= link_to "PDF", current_vehicle_reports_path(format: 'pdf', select_sort_order: params[:select_sort_order]), target: "_blank" %>
```

With the goal of being able to access the value in the controller via:

```
params[:select_sort_order]
```

So as far as I understand, the reason I'm not getting a value as desired from `params` is the lack of a form_tag. Could someone point me in the direction of how to pass the value from the `select_tag` to the controller. (if its possible)

Thanks

controller: (the if/else is just to test for now)

```
def current
  @report = Report.new(current_user.filter_start_date, current_user.filter_end_date, current_user.vehicle_group_ids, current_user.vehicle_sub_group_ids, "Current Asset Register", false, true, "date_reported", 0, current_user.vehicle_type_ids, true )

  if params[:select_sort_order] == "fleet_num"
    @report.data = Vehicle.left_outer_join_vehicle_tables("sold = false #{@report.where_clause}").order(:fleet_num)
  else
    @report.data = Vehicle.left_outer_join_vehicle_tables("sold = false #{@report.where_clause}").order(:rego)
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.pdf do
      render :pdf => "#{__method__}"
    end
    format.xlsx
  end
end
```

Comment: Added code to original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your view

```
<%= form_tag current_vehicle_reports_path, id: "report_form" do %>
    <%=   select_tag 'select_sort_order', "<option>fleet_num</option><option>rego</option>".html_safe %>
    <%= link_to "PDF", current_vehicle_reports_path(format: 'pdf'), id: 'report_id' %>
<%end %>
```

in application.js or in other js file

```
$('#report_id').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#report_form').attr('target', '_blank').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're PDF link won't be able to access from your `<select>` drop down. That's just not the way links work in HTML.

As far as I know you only have two options.

1. Wrap the `<select>` tag and the link in a `<form>` tag and switch your link to a button (you can still style it to look like a link in CSS if you want, if so use the `<button>` tag not the `<input type="submit">` tag).
2. Use javascript to take the value from the drop down and append it to the link tag like so: `?select_sort_order=...`.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you would need a **form_tag** and then a **submit_tag** (instead of a link).

Another approach would be to create both links passing select_sort_order explicitely, hide one of them, and then toggle showing each depending on the value of your select (using the **onchange** event). This approach doesn't need a form and would work.

I would go with the first option as it is cleaner.